# Silverlight Automated Load Testing

Tags: automation, performance-analysis

My company needs to load/performance test a Silverlight application on IE they developed. The test needs to generate large loads (2000+ threads/users), and allow for automation (record/replay or use of code). I've tried using JMeter, however that didn't work, and I'm very hesitant to use Selenium since it's been said the Selenium is not good for load testing.

The big thing they are testing is the UI load (render) times, which most programs don't have a way of telling you. I was wondering if anyone had an insight into a program I might use in order to performance test for render times in a silverlight application?

Thanks in advance!